# Magento catalog price rules not working when applying condition for manufacturer

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog-price-rules

I have one issue regarding catalog price rules,when i am creating any catalog price rule with the condition including manufacturer attribute in it, i am getting some catrgories 404 not found error on front end..can anyone help me regarding to this? it would be great help for me.

Comment: Any solution for that?